# Compile XAML to BAML in memory

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, baml

Is there a way in .Net, to compile an XAML `string` to a BAML `Stream` in memory,
without using MSBuild? PresentationBuildTask has some methods, but they always
use the file-system and are not very handy to use.

Thank you all a lot!

Comment: ConfuserEx on GitHub.

Comment: Isn't that not for obfuscation only?

Comment: check its source code. It contains BAML from/to XAML code, so that it can obfuscate WPF apps.

Comment: Could you give me a hint where to find the part? I only see obfuscating exeisting baml. Thank your for your patience :)